# Super big weird versions of prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm a little new to unity and I was making some collectable coins. I made some that work fine and when I right click a coin and duplicate it any duplicates created work as intended. I dragged the coin down into my assets folder and made a prefab. For some reason, anytime I place a coin into the game from this prefab, it comes up as this giant coin that follows the camera motion inverted. When I Look at it in the scene viewer it looks absolutely fine but in game it's massive. How do I fix this?

Attached are some screenshots all the scale values are set to one I checked.

in the scene view
[image: normal coins scene view]

Humongo coins in game view
[image: Humongo coin game view]

Comment: well its a little unclear from your pictures  - yes i see a large yellow thing on the right but not clear that is the details in the inspector, in fact it looks not, so, if the z level or other aspects are different and dropping something on the heirachy doesnt necessarily put it at the same lavel as other things.. it could also depend on what it is a child of

Comment: it would help a lot to se the Inspector of the coins in question, the working original and the prefab after spawning it

Comment: Is it a child of your canvas? just making sure